# How to show names and delete option for multiple selected file for uploading using wicket and html?

Tags: java, file, upload, wicket

```
<html>
<wicket:head>
</wicket:head>
<body>
    <form wicket:id="upload-form" action="">
    Upload content : <input wicket:id="uploadFile" type="file" value="Upload" multiple="multiple">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>



</body>
</html>
```

this is the HTML file i am using.

```
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 8637881868643000692L;
    private FileUploadField fileUpload;

    public UploadContentPage() {

        Form<ValueMap> form = new Form<ValueMap>("upload-form", new CompoundPropertyModel<ValueMap>(new ValueMap())) {
            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -7267140767240584618L;

            @Override
            public final void onSubmit() {
                // initialized = true;
                ValueMap values = getModelObject();

                // check if the honey pot is filled
                System.out.println("CreateOrderPage.CreateOrderPage().new Form() {...}.onSubmit() " + values);
                List<FileUpload> fileUpload2 = fileUpload.getFileUploads();



            @Override
            protected void onValidate() {
                System.out.println("clearing msgs...");
                Session.get().getFeedbackMessages().clear();
                super.onValidate();


            }
        };
        form.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        add(form);
        fileUpload = new FileUploadField("uploadFile");
        form.add(fileUpload)
```

this is my java class.. I am able to select multiple files but after selecting the file it is not showing the name and delete option infront of the name. Please help thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Standard HTML5 doesn't support this.

You need JavaScript widget for it. For example Wicket-Bootstrap has integrations with two such JS widgets. See http://wb-mgrigorov.rhcloud.com/extensions/BootstrapFileInput and http://wb-mgrigorov.rhcloud.com/extensions#dropzonefileupload